# Why my request POST swift to php, the content always to be key in PHP

Tags: php, swift, xcode

This is my first time, try swift to rest API PHP, i try request POST to PHP, but the key and value i request always to be key in php

i had try in swift 5, php 7

this is code in my swift:

```
func getTimeline(completion: @escaping (Result<MainResponse<String>, Error>) -> Void) {
    var param: [String: Any] = [:]
    param["device_id"] = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
    param["X_SIGNATURE_API"] = "X-secure"
    param["name"] = "Rangga Leo"

    let url = URLConst.server
    HTTPRequest.shared.connect(url: url, params: param, model: String.self) { (result) in
        completion(result)
    }
}
```

this is my URL ngrok if you want try : https://d9422a31.ngrok.io
anyway i have to create my own class to make dataTask more reuseable, and than this is simple response in my PHP :

```
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

$data = [
    "POST" => $_POST,
    "device_id" => $_POST["device_id"]
];

echo json_encode($data);
```

i expect the result show my device_id, but in case php given null value, event i debug $_POST, device_id is available but to be key in array PHP

btw, this is result in my console

```
{
"POST":{"{\"X_SIGNATURE_API\":\"X-secure\",
          \"name\":\"Rangga_Leo\",
          \"device_id\":\"C3E259A9-FBEB-4D65-9B6A-EC4F8BE89D95\"}":""},
"device_id":null
}
```

Comment: Both of the answers address the specific issue @Raggna Leo. You need to json_decode the response before accessing it as an associative array `$_POST["device_id"]`. You won't magically get a json object by putting that header since you are not using any kind of framework. You can only use the `Content-Type` header of the request and determine what kind of decoding it needs (assuming the endpoint accepts multiple request types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try bellow code to get json payload

```
$dataPayload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($dataPayload);
echo $dataPayload["device_id"];
```

or put this line to above of the line create data structure

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: its better and working, but i think not best solution, i had watch this video [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTj0ZLha1zE) , in 28:15 minute he get some problem with me, and added Content-Type, i had do that, but in my case with my URL, i get 0 array [] in post, i dont know why `{"POST":[],"device_id":null}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending a JSON object in the POST.

To read it from php you can replace your code with

```php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$decoded_data = json_decode($_POST);
$data = [
    "POST" => $_POST,
    "device_id" => $decoded_data["device_id"]
];

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: its better and working, but i think not best solution, i had watch this video [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTj0ZLha1zE) , in 28:15 minute he get some problem with me, and added Content-Type, i had do that, but in my case with my URL, i get 0 array [] in post, i dont know why `{"POST":[],"device_id":null}`

Comment: You are sending a json object as the body of your POST request.
PHP just sees a string containing a json object as the only thing inside $_POST. A json object is not automatically transformed into a PHP hashmap so you need to do it manually somewhere.
If you don't want to decode the json then you need to stop sending json and send something php actually understands.